# How to validate whether or not a single input line is only integers?

Tags: java, validation, while-loop, java.util.scanner

The program is supposed to receive four integers in a single input from the user (eg 1 2 3 42). I am trying to write some code to check whether or not the input is all integers.

However, even when the input is something like 1 2 a b, it does not enter the while loop, and i can't figure out why. any help would be appreciated.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);      
System.out.print("Please list at least one and up to 10 integers: ");
scan.hasNextInt();

    while(!scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.println("One or more of your inputs was not an integer. Please input only integers: ");
            scan.next();
        }
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you step through this with a debugger.  You will see at once what your error is.

Answer (score 1):

you are not progressing by reading next `int` with `Scanner`.

Try with input `1 a b` using the following code:

```
scan.hasNextInt();
scan.nextInt();   // or scan.next() to read next integer
    while(!scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.println("One or more of your inputs was not an integer. Please input only integers: ");
            scan.next();
        }
```

It will print:

> One or more of your inputs was not an integer. Please input only
>   integers:
>
> only integers:One or more of your inputs was not an integer. Please input

Comment: that does help, but i do not understand why the println iterates twice before the user can input again, why is that?

Comment: after reading first 1, the next token is `a` which is non integer and the condition of `while` loop results in `true`, so print the first line and then execute `scan.next()`. Now for second iteration it sees `b` which is non integer and `while` condition is again true. so it goes inside, print again and try to read `next()`. But nothing to read.